# ASP.Net Core Logging and DebugView.exe

Tags: logging, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I used to use DebugView.exe to view Debug messages from my web applications in classic ASP.Net.  I just need to use Debug.WriteLine("Message to display"); and it shows in the window on the DebugView.  I can also trace/view messages on the Production Server by using that method.
Eg. http://woutercx.com/2013/08/23/debugview-tool-how-it-saved-my-day/

In ASPNetCore, I am trying to do the samething by using the Logger.  I can view all the loggings correctly in VS2015 Output Window.  But I couldn't see it anymore in DebugView software.  And those logging messages are missing with other thousand of logging lines from MVC & ASP Engines and it's really difficult to view the messages which I only want to view.

Please see as an example in the picture below:

[image]

Is there anyway to view those logging messages in DebugView in ASP.Net Core?  Or anyway to get rid of those extra loggings in ASPNet.Core?

I did try to exclude those lines in Startup.cs... but no success yet.

```
loggerFactory.AddConsole((cat, level) => cat.StartsWith("WindowsAuthentication.") && level == LogLevel.Debug);
loggerFactory.AddDebug(LogLevel.Debug);
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the source only calls `Debug.WriteLine` if the Debugger is attached, meaning it is a no-op in production (unless you're remote debugging with a debugger attached). See the relevant source lines on GitHub at https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug/DebugLogger.cs#L48-L50. It says:

```
    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        // If the filter is null, everything is enabled
        // unless the debugger is not attached
        return Debugger.IsAttached &&
            logLevel != LogLevel.None &&
            (_filter == null || _filter(_name, logLevel));
    }
```

I suspect you could write your own Debug Logger Provider that looks almost identical to what is in GitHub but have the `IsEnabled` method disregard the `Debugger.IsAttached` check.